# How to pass hoverMoveEvent to underlaying items

Tags: qt

I have custom graphic item that draws some figure consisting of lines and polygons.
It has reimplemented method

```
hoverMoveEvent( QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent* event )
```

that indicates when need to highlight the figure (when mouse crosses the internal line or polygon ).

There are situations when items are drawn one above other, but hover event is accepted only by top item.
I tried to ignore event inside the method but it don't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem need to reimplement method

```
 QPainterPath QGraphicsItem::shape() const
```

in the custom item.

This shape should be exactly as a shape of "internal" painted items. Without empty spaces inside the bounding rectangle.